# How to store strings and integers in arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm attempting to read in an external file (.dat) that consists of strings and integers, in this format:

string 1

string 2

string 3, etc

And store these values into separate arrays (one array for the strings, one for the integers). However I can only manage to assign the first integer in the file, all subsequent integers and any strings present do not get assigned. Here is my code for this part in partiular:

```
char string[20]; /*20 is used as a placeholder for the time being*/
int integer[20];
FILE *inp2; /*pointer to input file 2*/    
int file_succeed1 =  fopen_s(&inp2,"C:\\Users\\input2b.dat", "r"); /*Boolean test*/
if (file_succeed1 != 0)
{
    printf_s("There was an error opening the file \n");
    return 0; /*The file failed to be read, end of program.*/

}



for(i = 0; i <=20; i++)
{
    fscanf_s(inp2, "%s", &string[i], 20);
    fscanf_s(inp2, "%d", &integer[i]);
}


fclose(inp2); /*close the input file*/
```

I get the warning messages when trying to print the information:

warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'

warning C4313: 'printf' : '%s' in format string conflicts with argument 1 of type 'int'

I've managed to read in and assign values of an external file that only consists of integers, however cannot figure out how to assign the strings or the subsequent integers in this case. Any help is great appreciated. Thank you.

NOTE: I've been advised explicitly to NOT use multidimensional arrays, but parallel arrays are OK.

Comment: If `printf` gives you errors, why do you post something different instead? Also: it should be `fscanf_s(inp2, "%s", string[i], 20);` and that leads to the next problem: you have only one buffer for one string, how do you want to safe the other ones without more memory? You can do without a 2d-array, but that will get much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define:

```
char string[20][20];
```

Read using:

```
if (fscanf_s(inp2, "%s %d", string[i], 20, &integer[i]) != 2)
    …report error and break loop…
```

If you're going to read up to 20 integers, you also need 20 strings, each of which needs some space for multiple characters.  Using a 2D array of characters is pretty straight-forward and doesn't require you to understand pointers.  The suggested code replaces two separate calls to `fscanf_s()` with one — it is perfectly capable of handling it.  Always check the I/O operations (especially input operations) for success.  Note that `fscanf_s()` could return EOF or 1 (and nominally 0) as well as 2, but only 2 indicates success.